# How to apply the same method multiple times to different array elements using a key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, toggle

I'm working with a gallery of cards in react.

Each card needs to have its own distinct state and toggle method, which is currently specified by a number at the end of the function, e.g. `onDropdownToggle1`.

The array is applied using `this.state.cards.map((product, key) => ( ...`.

Is there a way to call each function distinctly using the key in the name of the function? Like directly modifying the function name `onDropdownToggle + {key}`? Or is it better to take the key in as a parameter somehow?

Here is the link to my sandbox which shows exactly what's going on: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-worker-0y5vm

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the key as a parameter. Either do it inline like this:

```js
onToggle={(isDropdownOpen) => this.onDropdownToggle(key, isDropdownOpen)}
```

Or you could curry it like this:

```js
this.onDropdownToggle = key => isDropdownOpen => {
  ...
}

...

onToggle={this.onDropdownToggle(key)}
```

Then you can use a single handler to modify each card.

You will have to use a computed property name when settings state

```js
this.setState({
  [key]: isDropdownOpen
});
```

Final result:

```js
// One toggle function that uses the key to update state
this.onDropdownToggle = (key, isDropdownOpen) => {
  this.setState({
    [key]: isDropdownOpen
  });
};

// One dropdown select function that uses the key to update state
this.onDropdownSelect = (key, event) => {
  this.setState({
    [key]: !this.state[key]
  });
};

...


<Dropdown
  isPlain
  position="right"
  onSelect={(e) => this.onDropdownSelect(key,e)}
  toggle={
   <KebabToggle 
     onToggle={(isDropdownOpen) => this.onDropdownToggle(key, isDropdownOpen)} />}
  isOpen={this.state[key]}
  dropdownItems={kebabDropdownItems}
/>
```

You could also consider using the `item.name` instead of the key to pass to the functions. But only if they are always unique.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian! I'll definitely give this a try. What do you mean by using a single handler to modify each card?

Comment: I just updated the answer with a final result to hopefully be clearer. What I mean by a single handler is to have one function for toggle that is capable of toggling any value you pass it.

Comment: Wow, you rock! Having one function for toggle is definitely the optimal solution! Thank you so much for your help and for your super clear answer!!